# UnicodeEncodeError with django upgrade to 1.8

Tags: python, django

I upgrade django from 1.7.8 to 1.8.2 and test every page. When I try url "/admin/currencies/currency", [currencies](https://github.com/panosl/django-currencies) is a third package, UnicodeEncodeError throwed. But, other models in admin not throw UnicodeEncodeError, like "/admin/account/user"

error message

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/currencies/currency/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 164, in get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 158, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 135, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 135, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 329, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 329, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 217, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1195, in render
    return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_list.py", line 419, in admin_list_filter
    'spec': spec,
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 74, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/template_timings_panel/panels/TemplateTimings.py", line 137, in timing_hook
    result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 96, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 79, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/i18n.py", line 132, in render
    tmp_context[var] = val.resolve(context)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 674, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 45, in _dec
    args[0] = force_text(args[0])
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 94, in force_text
    s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)
  File "/Users/letsoon/Desktop/django1.8_test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 144, in __bytes_cast
    return bytes(func(*self.__args, **self.__kw))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your link:

> The updatecurrencysymbols command will add the currency symbol (if missing) to each currency present. Make sure that your symbol and name columns are set to UTF-8.

In your stack trace, it's trying to work with 'ascii'. See if there's a position in your code where you can specify the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `UTF-8` encoding by placing `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your script file, in your case either either first or second line of your admin.py for example.